# Testing event handlers in objects with jasmine

Tags: javascript, event-handling, coffeescript, jasmine

I am using a simple MVC pattern in my CoffeeScript ala [Spinejs](http://spinejs.com). It allows me to add event listeners by specifying an events object before instantiation:

```
class Controller extends Module
    @include Events

    eventSplitter: /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/
    events: {}

    constructor: (view = '<div/>') ->
        @view = $(view)
        @delegate key, func for key, func of @events

    delegate: (key, func) ->
        match = key.match @eventSplitter
        if match[2] is ''
            @view.on( match[1], $.proxy(@[func], @) )
        else
            @view.on( match[1], match[2], $.proxy(@[func], @) )
```

Quick explanation - You pass in a selector, element or html string which gets assigned to the view property. Then the delegate method takes an object of events and loops through and assigns event listeners to either the view node itself, or it delegates event handlers from child elements to the view node:

```
class Con extends Controller
    events:
        'click' : 'parent'
        'mouseover span' : 'child'

    parent: (e) ->
        console.log('div was clicked')

    child: (e) ->
        console.log('span was moused over')

con = new Con('<div><span>test</span></div>')

con.view.trigger('click') // --> 'div was clicked'
con.view.find('span') // --> 'span was moused over'
```

I'm struggling to test this with Jasmine. The following test will pass:

```
expect( con.view ).toHandle('mouseover')
expect( con.view ).toHandle('click')
```

Which at least allows me to test that some sort of handler is set, but I would like to test the actual handler being set. I'm trying to spy on the event handlers, but they never seem to be called.

```
spyOn(con, 'parent')
con.view.trigger('click')

expect( con.parent ).toHaveBeenCalled() // fails!
```

I also tried to spy on the actual method in the prototype.

```
spyOn( Con.prototype, 'parent' )
con.view.trigger('click')

expect( Con.prototype.parent ).toHaveBeenCalled() // fails!
```

I can get the test to pass if I call the method explicitly:

```
con.parent();
expect( con.parent ).toHaveBeenCalled() // passes!
```

I think the spy fails when executed by an event because of how the event handler is referenced through the jQuery 'on' method. as in it's a function, but it's not the actual method that's on the con object.

Any help would be appreciated. Any general testing advice is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be defining the spy outside of the object. I just discovered the jasmine.createSpy() method which creates a bare spy, exactly what I needed:

```
describe "Controller", ->
    clickSpy = jasmine.createSpy()
    mouseSpy = jasmine.createSpy()

    class Con extends CRDGN.Controller
        events:
            'click' : 'parent'
            'mouseover span' : 'child'

        parent: clickSpy

        child: mouseSpy

    con = new Con('<div><span>test</span></div>')

it "should attach listeners through an events object", ->
    con.view.trigger('click')
    expect( clickSpy ).toHaveBeenCalled()

    con.view.find('span').trigger('mouseover')
    expect( mouseSpy ).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine actually has a [`spyOn` method](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies) which allows you to do this without overriding your [System Under Test](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html).

I'll admit to not having run this specific code, but here is a refactor of your answer which uses `spyOn` and splits out your two tests.

```
describe 'CRDGN.Controller', ->
  it 'should attach a click listener', =>
    clickSpy = spyOn(CRDGN.Controller, 'parent')
    controller = @_buildController()

    controller.view.trigger('click')

    expect(clickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  it 'should attack a mouseover listener for <span>', =>
    mouseSpy = spyOn(CRDGN.Controller, 'child')
    controller = @_buildController()

    controller.view.find('span').trigger('mouseover')

    expect(mouseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  _buildController: () ->
    new CRDGN.Controller('<div><span>test</span></div>')
```